# How to check if a transaction is marked for rollback?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jta, transactional

I am currently coding a webservice for user management. This project involves both a Oracle DB and a XMPP chat server. I am using Eclipselink, JPA and JTA for transaction management.

When registering a new user I've run into a problem which I can't seem to be able to fix with my knowlege of JTA.

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = XMPPException.class)
public User registerUser(User user) throws InvalidArgumentException, NullValueException, ConstraintViolationException, XMPPException {

    if (user == null) {
        throw new NullValueException(new ErrorBuilder(Error.USER_NULL));
    }
    if (user.getEmail() != null && !EmailUtils.isEmailValid(user.getEmail())) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(new ErrorBuilder(Error.INVALID_EMAIL).withParams(user.getEmail()));
    }

    Character gender = getGenderOrDefault(user.getGender());
    user.setGender(gender);
    user.setRole(UserRole.USER.getChar());

    em.persist(user);

    //only add xmpp user if registration was successful (if transaction is not marked for rollback)
    if (!em.getTransaction().getRollbackOnly()) {     //throws Exception because I'm using JTA
        xmppService.createUser(user);
    }

    return user;
}
```

The problem is that I need to create the new user in both the Oracle DB and the XMPP server (using their API). This means that if one of the two seperate creation processes fails I need to rollback the other one as well.

However, since em.persist() doesn't throw an Exception immediately but rather mark the transaction for rollback the method execution continues and the user is created on the XMPP server.

My initial idea was to just check if the transaction was marked for rollback, but that doesn't seem to be able when using JTA.

So my question is: How should I go about this problem? I really don't want to split it in 2 seperate methods and just delete the user from the Oracle DB if XMPP fails.

Comment: I can't properly answer this from my phone. The point is, however, that you must choose between container managed transactions (`@Transactional`) and bean managed transactions (`em.getTransaction().doSomething()`)'

Comment: I know, but the problem is that the container managed transaction does not abort the method execution if em.persist() fails. This way the user is always created on the XMPP server, even if it shouldn't.

Comment: Apparently, the CMT does not manage the xmpp calls. So you need to fall back on Bean Managed Transactions.

Comment: I found kind of a solution. I just call `em.flush()` after all Oracle operations. This will abort the execution of the method and not create the user on the XMPP server.